# Rust function signatures and outliving

Tags: types, rust, closures, lifetime, ownership

To learn Rust, I'm writing a parser combinator library. Now I have a problem that spans a complicated slice type and ownership. I have some building block functions I'd like to be able to use separately:

```rust
pub fn achar(character: char) -> impl Fn(&str) -> Option<char> {
    move |input| match input.chars().next() {
        Some(c) if c == character => Some(c),
        _ => None,
    }
}

pub fn alternatives<'a, T>(
    alts: &'a [impl Fn(&'a str) -> Option<T>],
) -> impl Fn(&'a str) -> Option<T> {
    move |input| {
        for alt in alts.iter() {
            let tried = alt(input);
            if tried.is_none() {
                continue;
            }
            return tried;
        }

        None
    }
}

pub fn one_of<'a>(allowed: &'a str) -> impl Fn(&'a str) -> Option<char> {
    let v = allowed.chars().map(achar).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    alternatives(&v)
}
```

Usage would then look like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", achar('f')("foo"));
    println!("{:?}", alternatives(vec![achar('f'), achar('b')])("foo"));
    println!("{:?}", one_of("foo")("foo"));
}
```

Like that I get the following error:

```
   = note:   expected type `for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> std::option::Option<char> {any_char}`
           found reference `&impl for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(&'r str,)>`
```

I would say that `quote` implements `Fn(&str)`, doesn't it? How can I get this working?

---

Once that would be solved the next problem is at the door:

```
33 |     alternatives(&v)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^--^
   |     |            |
   |     |            `v` is borrowed here
   |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Of course, inlining doesn't solve the problem. I don't have any idea how one might go attack this.

[Playground is available here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f599b46ffaa8a1f59cf10da7e1f1d353)

Comment: The code in your post doesn't lead to the same error as the code in the playground.

Comment: Thanks [trentcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61288606/rust-function-signatures-and-outliving#comment108424727_61288606). While writing this post, I was still trying to get it to work. I must have mixed up versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things going on here:

```
pub fn alternatives<'a, T>(
    alts: &'a [impl Fn(&'a str) -> Option<T>],
) -> impl Fn(&'a str) -> Option<T> {
    move |input| {
        ...
    }
}
```

The above tells that `alternatives` requires that all elements in the slice `alts` are of the same type, and that this type implements `Fn(&'a str) -> Option<T>`. However, in the call `let escaping = alternatives(&vec![any_char, &quote, &backslash]);` (or even simply `vec![any_char, &quote, &backslash];`), the elements have different types (one is `any_char`-type, the next `quote`-type, and so on). On the other hand, `vec![achar('f'), achar('b')]` works since all elements have `achar`-type.

That is, even if all the elements implement `Fn(&str)->Option`, they are not exactly of the same type.

Regarding the next error:

```
pub fn one_of<'a>(allowed: &'a str) -> impl Fn(&'a str) -> Option<char> {
    let v = allowed.chars().map(achar).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    alternatives(&v)
}
```

Here, you return `alternatives(&v)` which *borrows* `v`. But `v` goes out of scope at the end of `one_of`, meaning that the result from `alternatives` would refer to something that has been destroyed, thus rust disallows this.

Now, what can we do regarding the types accepted by `alternatives`?

- `alternatives` could accept boxed functions. This, however, incurs some runtime overhead, but would allow for the number of alternatives to be dynamic at runtime.
- `alternatives` could accept function pointers. This, however, would forbid (environment capturing) closures.
- `alternatives` could accept 2 functions, and more than two functions could be supplied via a macro. This would basically fix the number of alternatives at compile time, but has no runtime overhead.

What can we do about the lifetime issue in `one_of`?

- This could actually also be considered an issue in `alternatives`, as `alternatives` should possibly accept some functions as arguments and keep them so that the caller does not need to worry about lifetime issues.

Comment: I can live with `alternatives` taking ownership and changed that. But I'm surprised that you cannot pass an array of functions that all behave the same (i. e. same signature and all). Would a slice work better than a `Vec`?

Comment: The problem with functions having only the same signature is that they might be closures, i.e. some might "capture" variables (such as you `achar` capturing a character).

Comment: If you want to take ownership, a `Vec` is probably the better option (as slice does not onw its data while `Vec` does).